# Solve $(x-2y^3)dx+3y^2(2x-y^3)dy=0$ with the change of variables $y=z^{\alpha}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

***Question:***

> Solve the ODE $(x-2y^3)dx+3y^2(2x-y^3)dy=0$ with the change of variables $y=z^{\alpha}$

---

I did what the question asked and here is the result:

$(x-2z^{3\alpha})dx+3z^{2\alpha}(2x-z^{3\alpha})(\alpha z^{\alpha-1})dz=0 \implies (x-2z^{3\alpha})dx+(6\alpha x z^{3\alpha-1}-3\alpha z^{6\alpha-1}) dz=0$

Now, I don't know how to continue. I mean, It seems that there is no clue.  Any idea?

Note: I know how to solve a homogenous ODE. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $y^3=z$ we get
$$
(x-2z)dx+(2x-z)dz=0
$$
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{x-2z}{z-2x}
$$
this is homogeneous equation and can be solved by standard techniques.

Comment: The question wants you to solve the ODE with $y=z^\alpha$, not $y^3=z$

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade $y^3=z$ means $y=z^{1/3}$.

Comment: Yes, But how did you know that it would work?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade it was obvious.

Comment: So, Why not $y^2=z$ ?

Comment: -1: @UziaRoid Because of "it was obvious". If it was obvious the question would not have been asked here. This kind of attitude is not acceptable for MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You are almost there. Look at your equation and try to get it into a homogeneous differential form (this means the coefficients are linear combinations of $x$ and $z$:

$(x-2z^{3\alpha})dx+(6\alpha x z^{3\alpha-1}-3\alpha z^{6\alpha-1}) dz=0$

Can you see that $\alpha = 1/3$ puts the equation into homogeneous form? Also observe that the term $xz^{3\alpha-1}$ has to become $x$ times a constant. A homogeneous differential equation can be solved by the substitution $z(x)=xy(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I know that $\alpha=1/3$ converts it to homogenous form. But, why a special $\alpha$? Can't we solve it with a general $\alpha$?

Comment: This is the easiest way to solve it. There might be some other $\alpha$ value that allows us to solve the ODE, but this might lead to a difficult ODE that is harder to solve. $\alpha = 1/3$ allows us to obtain a simple ODE that we can solve, hence it is the easiest choice that we can make.